# MYSQL Query: JOIN Using Value from tbl 1 and concate to tbl 2

Tags: mysql, join

i'm trying to do something like this:

tbl1:

`MatNr|  text` 
`------------` 
`100  |  lala`

tbl2:
`MART   |  lolo` 
`--------------` 
`100.1  |  miau`

I need something like this:
Result
tbl1:

`MatNr   |  MART   |  text   | lolo` 
`----------------------------------` 
`100     |  100.1 |  lala    | miau`

I Try to use a simple Join Like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 on MatNr = concat(MART, '.1')
```

but it leeds not to the expected result.

How can I use the MatNr and concat the '.1' to the joining table?

Thank you so much for your Help!

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1  
JOIN tbl on concat(MatNr, '.1') = MART
```

leads to the perferct result.
Thank you Sami Kuhmonen

Comment: You have MatNr and MART reversed in your query

Comment: Thank you, but reversing the order leeds to no result :(

Comment: no you were right:  SELECT *
JOIN tbl1 on concat(MatNr, '.1') = MART were perfekt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work assuming varchar:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 on concat(MatNr,'.1') = MART
```

This will work assuming number:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 
JOIN tbl2 on MatNr = floor(MART)
```